# Why doesn't answers.ros.org use HTTPS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't like sending passwords in the clear. With Let's Encrypt available these days it's hard to think of a good reason.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260620/why-doesn%27t-answers.ros.org-use-https?/) by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're working to add encryption to our various services as we have time available. If you would like to securely log in I recommend using one of the several OAuth providers who can authenticate you using https in the mean time.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1